# Celery Task not working

Tags: redis, celery, delay

every time I try to use delay() nothing happens.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

@app.task
def run(msg):
    print(msg)

word="xxx"
run.delay(word)
```

I checked redis with ping and it seems to be working.
Or maybe I should use something different to run background threads in Flask app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start worker in order to pick up the task to process.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#id9